# TCL expect re get substring with expect_out

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have a question about regular expressions in expect, I use the following expression:
The string to match is:

```
pwd
/root
root@FLC320-14-ACT:/root#
```

I want to find the "/root" with following expect

```
send "pwd\r"
expect -re {
 "(.*)pwd(\/root)(.*):\/root#" { puts "$expect_out(1.string)" }
 timeout { 
            exit
        }
```

expect -d says:

```
expect: does " pwd\r\n/root\r\nroot@FLC320-14-ACT:/root# 
" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression 
"\n "(.*)pwd(\/root)(.*):\/root#" { puts "$expect_out(1.string)" }\n
 timeout { "\n\t\t\tsend "exit\r"\n\t\t\texit\n\t\t}\n"? Gate "\n "*pwd/root*:/root#" { puts "expect_out1?string" }\n timeout { send "exit\r"\n\t\t\texpect "em*,gadmin,alcatel #"\n\t\t\tsend "exit\r"\n\t\t\texit\n\t\t}\n"? gate=no
expect: timed out
```

How is the expression to get the "/root" statement in expect_out(X,string). I am new to the regex and want to learn.

Comment: Try `pwd\s(\/root)\s([^:]+):\/root#` https://regex101.com/r/dGuR68/1

Comment: it doesn't work. I have change to pwd\\s(\/root)\\s(\[^:]+):\/root# because of escaping the Bracket in [^:] and escape the \s. but it doesnt work either: 
expect: does " pwd\r\n/root\r\nroot@FLC320-14-ACT:/root# " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "pwd\s(/root)\s([^:]+):/root#"? Gate "pwd?/root*:/root#"? gate=no
expect: timed out

Comment: It's usually best to explicitly set PS1 and (if you're unlucky) PS2 on any shell you're automating with Expect so that you can match prompts far more easily. Variable prompts are very annoying to match reliably!

Comment: Not sure if you have to use Tcl, if not you can take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./pwd.sh
send pwd\r
expect {
    -re {pwd\s+/root\s+(.+):/root#} { puts "Got $expect_out(1,string)" }
    timeout { puts "Timed out!"; exit }
}
```

A few things.

You had braces set up in a not-wrong but not giving you what you wanted sense for the arguments to the `expect` command. The whole expression in braces after the `-re` was treated as a single regular expression. See the right way to do it above.

It's `$expect_out(N,string)` to get the text of the Nth capturing group. You had a period, not a comma (And probably the wrong group for your RE).

You don't have any white space between `pwd` and `/root` when there is since they're on different lines.

Unless you turn on newline sensitive mode (See the [TCL regular expression syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) documentation for details, `.` won't match a newline. `\s` will, though.

You don't need to escape forward slashes.

---

And `pwd.sh` for testing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
read -r foo
printf "%s\n" pwd /root 'root@FLC320-14-ACT:/root#'
```

Comment: Also as a general rule, to prevent unwanted interpolation and stripping of backslashes, regular expressions in tcl should be enclosed in braces.

Comment: `printf '%s\r\n'` -- `\r` is not necessary here. for most of time people just use `\n`.

Comment: @pynexj I know; glen edited the answer to add it for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. That works for me. I am still learning about re Pattern. Until now i have work only with glob pattern.